# How to configure web farm in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, web-farm

What changes are required in web.config file to configure Web Farm ?

Comment: Not a very clear question (more info required). But i think you're talking about the <machineKey> element: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx.

Comment: Sounds like an interview question.

Comment: All web farm environments are different, may be you need to provide more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, when asked this in an interview, you will be expected to know that all machines in a web farm should have the same [`<machineKey>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9.aspx).

Read more details [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20030514.asp) (Generate Machine Key Elements for Web Farm).

Comment: You will also need to address Session management.  in-memory Session won't be shared across servers, so you either have to use the SQL mode, StateServer mode, or a custom provider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

Comment: I just want to add that this answer presupposes that one is using webforms and session state.  If you're using MVC and sworn off MS's session state you don't really need a machine key for web farms.